# AngularJS how to change width of container on resize

Tags: angularjs

#### AngularJS 1.5> $doCheck after stoped rendering

I'm trying to build a D3 chart inside a AngularJS component. I wan't to update when data changes ( by one way binding ) or when the chart is made bigger via a Button.

As far as I got is using $doCheck (because $onChange is not fired when data is updated or when parent resize happens ). The problem is that $doCheck is fired before the parent is finished rendering ( Container width is the old one ).

If you have any tips it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: one way binding would not watch when the data changes. two way binding does that. thats probably why change event is not being fired.

Comment: Thanks but my main issue is with the resize ... I want to change Width of container of component and the component to resize in relation to that ... This is a D3 chart so I need to recalculate axis and the data.

Comment: This is an example to an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking how to enable the AngularJS app to react to a [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) you are trying to solve the problem with `$doCheck`.